# sql synthesis query

Tags: sql

good morning.
Can anyone help me with the query, summarizing the total code in each table (Table 1 + table 2) as in table 3, thanks a lot.
Sorry, my english is not good

[image]

Comment: Don't close this, please. Understand that not everyone can convey their thoughts well in written English. At least they are trying. Please help them as much as you can rather than downvoting and closing their questions.

Comment: Hello - Welcome to SO. Please give more details like if all codes will be in both tables or if one of the tables is the driving tables for codes as it drives what kind of join will be needed. Also pls see - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Can you tag what is the dialect you are using (MSSQL, Oracle, MySQL...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are trying to do:

```
select codes.codename, t1.c as Table1, t2.c as Table2
from (
  select codename from table1
  union select codename from table2
) codes
left join (select codename, count(*) c from table1 group by codename) t1 on codes.codename = t1.codename
left join (select codename, count(*) c from table2 group by codename) t2 on codes.codename = t2.codename
group by codes.codename
order by codes.codename;
```

Example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=74d3bf30af406a2cdf65185a5fdcc564

**Explanation**

There are 2 subqueries t1 and t2. Both of them take a count of each code from each of the tables. The codes subquery combines codenames from both tables in case one table had more codes than the other.

Then, using the combined codenames connect with t1 and t2 and collect its respective counts.

**Result**

> ```
> codename | Table1 | Table2
> :------- | -----: | -----:
> code1    |      2 |      1
> code2    |      2 |      3
> code3    |      1 |      1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.code, count(A.Date) as bang_1 , B.bang_2
FROM table_1 A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT code,count(*) as bang_2 
           FROM table_2
           GROUP BY code) B ON A.code = B.code
GROUP BY A.code, B.bang_2
```

Comment: I tried this same method but got the incorrect count since code #1 from one table will join multiple records for the same code #1 in another table.

Comment: Yes. Missed it in oversight. Edited my answer now.

Comment: Great. This gives the answer that OP needs.